# How to display image with upload button in and resize it with window resize (Dynamically)with Tkinter python, I need to add upload button

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I need to add upload button so that I can upload the picture and display with this class. Everything working but when I am adding the upload button its giving me some error and my code is not wokring.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Layout:
    
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.rootgeometry()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.background_image = Image.open(self.openfn())
        self.image_copy = self.background_image.copy()
        self.background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.background_image)
        self.loadbackground()
             
                   

    def loadbackground(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self.canvas, image = self.background)
        self.label.bind('<Configure>',self.resizeimage)
        self.label.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
    
    def openfn(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='open')
        return filename
    


    def rootgeometry(self):
        x=int(self.master.winfo_screenwidth()*0.7)
        y=int(self.master.winfo_screenheight()*0.7)
        z = str(x) +'x'+str(y)
        self.master.geometry(z)

    def resizeimage(self,event):
        image = self.image_copy.resize((self.master.winfo_width(),self.master.winfo_height()))
        self.image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.label.config(image = self.image1)

root = tk.Tk()
a = Layout(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: I dont know exactly where to add upload button option in this code.

Comment: @Vibhu where do you want to add the upload button? On the image?

Comment: @JacksonPro Actually I want an upload button option and when I select the image with that button it should display with the code I mentioned. So with this code it will open the option for choosing file directly and then displaying the image in window. But i want to choose file with open/upload button.

Comment: As you said *"when I am adding the upload button its giving me some error"*, so you have tried but get error.  Post what you have tried and the traceback of the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `Button` widget within the class constructor and bind it with `self.loadbackground`. Also, you don't need to recreate the `Label` widget every time instead use `label.configure(image=yourimage)`.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Layout:
    
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.rootgeometry()

        self.button = Button(self.master, text='Upload', command=self.loadbackground)
        self.button.pack()
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.background_image = None
        self.image_copy = None
        self.background = None

        self.label = tk.Label(self.canvas)
        self.label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        

    def loadbackground(self):

        self.background_image = Image.open(self.openfn())
        self.image_copy = self.background_image.copy()
        
        self.background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.background_image.resize((self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height())))
        self.label.configure(image=self.background)
        self.label.bind('<Configure>',self.resizeimage)

    def openfn(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='open')
        return filename
    

    def rootgeometry(self):
        x=int(self.master.winfo_screenwidth()*0.7)
        y=int(self.master.winfo_screenheight()*0.7)
        z = str(x) +'x'+str(y)
        self.master.geometry(z)

    def resizeimage(self,event):
        image = self.image_copy.resize((event.width, event.height))
        self.image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.label.config(image = self.image1)
        

root = tk.Tk()
a = Layout(root)
root.mainloop()
```